# How do I toggle between greying out & allowing input on a parameter in Report Builder 3.0?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I found a nice way to set the default values based on the first parameter chosen. That works well. *However*, when the user changes that first parameter to something else, the other parameters don't change accordingly.

I need to make it so that if the user changes that first parameter, then one group of parameters gets changed to *allow user input* and the other two groups become grayed out. There are 3 groups of parameters. How can I do this? The tricky part is that I can't select available values from a data set for the "allow user input" part because I don't want to give the user some available values. Instead, they need to be able to start writing in their values right there.

**Visual description of how it currently works and the last pic is the desired result**

User first selects the method:
[image]

After selecting "Direct Input", the report correctly makes the first group of parameters allow for input:
[image]

Now I try to change the method parameter and select the second option (the screenshot below just shows you all options in the drop-down):
[image]

The report should now gray out the first group of parameters and allow input to the second group, but as you can see below, it does not do this:
[image]

This is what it ***should*** have done:
[image]

Comment: Some code or screenshots can help get desired answer quickly.

Comment: @SurjitSD added pics.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what you are after is referred to as a Cascading Parameter. The value of Method will determine the value of the Ignore This parameter right? This article may of use: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337498(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @SQLUser44 No, the parameter labeled "ignore this" should literally be ignored. Please pretend it's not there for the purposes of this question.

Comment: The method parameter should determine whether or not all the other parameters are grayed out/fillable.

Comment: Cascading Parameters is not what I'm looking for.